# C++ SDL Collision based on Angles

Tags: c++, sdl, collision, angle

I am in the process of creating a Pong clone using c++ and SDL.

I am trying to make the collision and bounce of the ball based on angles.
i have successfully created such method but it fails at angles that are very close to 90, 180, 270, or 0 degrees, which results it a bit of lag and not so precise/correct bounce.

this is the code that makes the ball bounce within all boundries of the screen:

```
void Ball::wall_collision(SDL_Surface *S){

   //bounds of the screen
    if(x - radius < 0 || x + radius > S->w || y - radius < 0 || y + radius > S->h){

       // add 2*pi rads to current direction      
       direction = direction + d_pi;

    }
 }
```

This ofcourse doesnt fail completely, the ball does bounce correctly, but lags and sometimes bounces improperly at angles close to 180,0,90,270 degrees like previously declared.

Another thing, im declaring the "direction" (direction of the ball in rads) and "d_pi" (which is pi doubled) variables as floats but when d_pi has a decimal precision such as 6.28318531 radians the collision fails completely, no bouncing occurs but when i change "d_pi" to something like 6.0 or 6.1, the collision works. I dont know why that error occurs but it causes innaccuracy when calculating a new direction.

i would like to know a way to fix that "d_pi" variable problem or know of any other methods to have collision/bounce based on ANGLE of direction in 2d space ofcourse,(no friction or gravity just in a simple pong environment).

Comment: Is the probematic angle perpendicular or parallel to the wall?

Comment: Why are you adding 2*pi? That's a full circle. Unless you divide direction at some point, values of sin and cos shouldn't change. If you added pi instead, you'd get 180 degree flip. Although correct reflection should work by changing the sign of one of velocity coordinates (in simple cases. There is a general formula too). I don't know how that could be done with angles.

Comment: well i found a pattern and by colliding on to any surface, the ball should change at angle of the current direction plus a full revolution, it works i already tested it, the problem is at angles that are near perpendicular to wall since it causes lag and improper bounces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess that at these angles, for some reason, the condition is satisfied twice (and thus many more times). The problem is that you are only checking the position of the ball, while to bounce, it also has to go in the right direction.

Try this

```
if(x - radius < 0 && speed_x < 0 || x + radius > S->w && speed_x > 0 || y - radius < 0 && speed_y < 0 || y + radius > S->h && speed_y > 0) ...
```

Here speed_x and speed_y are sin(direction) and cos(direction), possibly swapped or with some coefficients. Take them from where you update x and y values.

Comment: yea i thought so too(direction that the ball is going), but the pattern that i found for bouncing on any flat surface only needs this change of angle: curren_angle + 360degrees. i also think that the problem might come from the "d_pi" variable because i lose precision, for some reason it only takes a number with a low precision like 6.1 instead of a more accurate value of pi doubled